# Deformed Template/Image Matching

Tags: python, image, opencv, numpy, comparison

Well, i've been wondering what would be a good way to go about finding *deformed* subimages in a image/template. At this moment i'm using cv2.matchTemplate, and it works from time to time, it depends on the tolerance-level given, and the background "noise": Other objects might be similar, and therefore returned as a result if the tolerance is to high.

Current algo goes something like this (pseudo) / returns only one match (got a similar for multi match - which is the actual case in this question):

```
haystack = im.read("stack.bmp")
image = Image.open("im.bmp")
MATCH = []
PIL_rotateImage for 0 to 360: # You get the point..
    image = np.array(rotatedImage)
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(image, haystack, algorithm) #algorithm: CCOEFF_NORMED
    resultMax = result.max()
    y,x = np.unravel_index(result.argmax(), result.shape)
    MATCH.append([resultMax, (x,y)])

Best_match = sorted(MATCH, key=itemgetter(0))[0] 
if Best_match[0] < minval: return False
*.....*
```

Let's say you have a template containing an subimage which is deformed (partial, and/or rotated), it's the exact same image (to the human eye):

1. The object can be rotated
2. The object can be partial (but to a tolerated level - Eg: 60%)
3. The colors are not always the same, but similar. (got an algo for comparing colors)
4. The object is not always there...
5. The object can be a little deformed: Some pixels can be "missplaced"
6. Something might be forgot: but in general: DEFORMED.

I've also tried iterating over list, but this is obviously slow, and the way i did it was simply by checking if some of the first/last, or center pixels where the same.. <- Ofcourse not working for finding partial, or rotated objects.

A small images (example) to back my writing, to help your understanding:
Only an example!

[image]

**Q**: Does anyone got any tips, pseudo-code, or acutal code on how to go about this? Something that can give me a start, as i'm constantly getting lost.

Comment: So largely affine transformations? I suggest [dsp.stackexchange.com](http://dsp.stackexchange.com) to be a better place to ask this question. There have been lots of research papers written on this problem! As a starting point, my [former supervisor](http://www-sigproc.eng.cam.ac.uk/~ngk/) does this kind of work.

Comment: @HenryGomersall - That would be correct. I will take a look at dsp.stackexchange.com, I've read some research (parts atleast), but to formulate thies ideas in any prog.lang isn't as easy as one would hope:)